# R: Difference between log axis scale vs. manual log transformation?

Tags: r, plot

```
set.seed(2) 
x = c(1, rnorm(100, 15, 5))
y = c(1, rnorm(100, 15, 5))

plot(x, y, log = "xy")
plot(log(x), log(y))
```

What is the difference when i use `log`-argument in `plot()` function and when i transform the variables first, then plot them. Hier is the plot with `plot(x, y, log = "xy")`. [image]

And with `plot(log(x), log(y))` [image]

Can someone explain me what does the `log`-argument exactly do? Thank you.

Comment: I mean … just compare your two plots. Hint: look at the axes.

Comment: Sorry if you feel my question is bad. But believe me or not. It maybe obvious to you but not to me.

Comment: What i dont understand is the axes. In the plot(log(x), log(x)) the values on x- and y-axis are exact what log(x) and log(y) are. But why the values on the plot with log = "xy" are different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For log-plots you do not have to modify your data. It is just a matter of displaying, so that you can further work with your data. Just as example:

```
set.seed(2) 
x = c(1, rnorm(100, 15, 50))
y = c(1, rnorm(100, 15, 50))

plot(x, y, col = "black",
     log = "xy", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n",)

# Labels...
at.y <- outer(1:9, 10^(log10(1):log10(100)))
lab.y <- ifelse(log10(at.y) %% 1 == 0,
                sapply(at.y, function(i)
                  as.expression(bquote(10^.(log10(i))))
                ), NA)
axis(2, at = at.y, labels = lab.y, las = 1)

at.x <- outer(1:9, 10^(0:log10(100)))
lab.x <- ifelse(log10(at.x) %% 1 == 0,
                sapply(at.x, function(i)
                  as.expression(bquote(10^.(log10(i))))
                ), NA)
axis(1, at = at.x, labels = lab.x, las = 1)
grid (NULL,NULL, lty = 6, col = "cornsilk2")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: First thank you for your answer. It would be nice if you can confirm that i understand it correctly: Because the plots of logirithm scale of all bases look identically (except the values on the axes), so R simply plots the values of 10^... (and not exp(...)) on the axes. And that's the reason why the distances, for-instance 1-5 and 5-10, not the same.

Comment: I am not sure: I would say the scale is log - not the data. That is what it is about. But yes, in log-scale plots the ticks are not "linearly distributed"... I hope that helps.